# Create a nested document with Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, model, mongoid

I'm a rookie in Ruby and Mongoid and I need a bit of help to create a model and  modeling a document.

This is the structure that the document must be have

```js
{
  key1 : "value",
  key2 : "value",
  key3 : {
    key3.1 : "value",
    key3.2 : [array]
  },
  key4 : {
    key4.1 : "value",
    key4.2 : [
      {
       "key4.2.1" : "value",
       "key4.2.2" : "value",
       "key4.2.3" : "value",
       "key4.2.4" : [
          "key4.3.1"  : "value",
          "key4.3.1" : "value",
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
  } 
}
```

And my model looks like this:

```ruby
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :key1, type: Integer
  field :key2, type: Integer
  field :key3, type: Hash
  field :key4, type: Hash
end
```

Is possible to make this structure with MongoId?
I know that my model is incorrect and incomplete.

Comment: I think you can't have dots in field names.

Comment: Is only an example, is not a really naming. These keys and those values ​​are only for the shortest example

Comment: I think people are wondering what you are asking aside from [looking at the documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#embeds_many). Perhaps you should look at that and then either possibly re-phrase your question for what you do not understand or if you learn something then this is possibly not a question for someone to answer and you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean where key4.2.4 is an array which has keyed values, but Mongoid will save your object as defined.

Using a simplified Model:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :key1, type:Integer
  field :key2, type:Hash
end
```

You can exercise it as so:

```
m = Model.new
m.key1 = 12
m.key2 = {a: 1, b:[{c: 2, e: [23,34]}]}
m.save

Model.first
=> #<Model _id: 53ab8ed1cac11f4c94000004, key1: 12, key2: {"a"=>1, "b"=>[{"c"=>2, "e"=>[23, 34]}]}>
```

So you can see that all of your embedded hashes and arrays are saved to the MongoDB and retrieved by Mongoid without any problem.

It is also possible to use an embedded document (another Mongoid document contained within its enclosing document) or a related document, where the key to the related document is stored in the parent document.  If you want to do it that way, the documentation at http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html should be helpful.